# Difference between C++ struct and class issue

Tags: c++, class, struct

I had a structure containing data, sometimes used as a static item in a header, sometimes filled programmatically.  I thought it would be neater to have a few of the data members be initialized with default values, so I made it into a class with a constructor and got an error I don't know how to get around.

If I have this:

```
struct ThisThing {
    int A;
    int B;
};
static ThisThing TT1 = {1,2};
```

works, as does this:

```
class ThisThing {
public:
    int A;
    int B;
};
static ThisThing TT1 = {1,2};
```

but this fails:

```
class ThisThing {
public:
    ThisThing(){};
    int A;
    int B;
};
static ThisThing TT1 = {1,2};
```

with this error:

```
error: could not convert '{1, 2}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'thisthing
68 | static ThisThing TT1 = { 1,2 }
   |                              ^
   |                              |
   |                              <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

So, how do I make this work?  And is it then different if I use an initializer list in the constructor for some of the members, like this for instance?

`ThisThing(): A(0); {};`

Of course my real struct is more complicated, there are three int members I would like to have a default value for, and then a 2K buffer for data. Some instances are static, some are dynamically created and the data calculated.  I can get around this as I originally had it with a struct, and when I create a variable using the struct just initialize those members I want to have a default value, but this bugged me that I could not figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: Aggregates are initialized like your working examples. When you add a constructor it ceases to be an aggregate so you have to have a specific constructor for the arguments. [see this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) Aggregate initialization allows for simple use of structs/classes with all public members.

Comment: What do you expect your default constructor to actually do? It does nothing. So, get rid of it. Problem solved.

Comment: this has nothing to do with struct vs class. The only difference between classes defined with the keyword `class` and those defined with the keyword `struct` is default member access

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai There are *two* differences actually; default member access is one, and default inheritance mode of `public` or `private` inheritance (when not explicitly specified) being the other. But other than that, `struct` and `class` are exactly the same.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, Obviously this is not the real code, the real thing has a large buffer and 7 other variables, this is the 'simple' version to find the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want default values for the members, then just use [default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

```
struct ThisThing {
    int A = 0;
    int B = 42;
};
```

They exist since C+11, and your object even stays an aggregate since C++14 if you use them (the aggregate initialization in your sample will continue to work). They are self-documenting, consistent (if you add multiple constructors, you don't have to duplicate default values across all of them), and hell convenient.

Only caveat is members of aggregates are initialized in order from the arguments that appear in the braces `{}`, so default member initializers in aggregates are typically more useful when they appear on later members.

Answer (score 0):

when you don't implement atleast one constructor C++ give you a hand with {} to be able to create instances.
but when you make an empty constructor now the compiler thinks the only way to create an instance is by calling that empty constructor and manipulate the object later.

instead you can define a constructor like this

```
class ThisThing {
public:
    ThisThing(int a, int b){
        A = a; B = b;
};
    int A;
    int B;
};
static ThisThing TT1 = ThisThing(1,2);
```

Comment: `ThisThing(int a, int b){
        A = a; B = b;
};` - don't do that. Don't assign to members in the constructor body when you can initialize them in the initialization list: `ThisThing(int a, int b) : A(a), B(b) {};`. For one it is more efficient, by not having to default construct objects only to subsequently assign to them, and secondly, not all objects *can* be default constructed and/or assigned to, but such objects can still be initialized. So your version is inefficient and doesn't actually work for many objects - initialization works for more objects, is more efficient, prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Ctor == constructor, CCtor == copy constructor

class ThisThing {
public:
    ThisThing(): A(1), B(2) {};             // Ctor #1: given no arguments sets to default values 
    ThisThing(int a, int b): A(a), B(b) {}; // Ctor #2: given two args programmatically  

    int A;
    int B;
};

static ThisThing obj1;         //uses Ctor #1
static ThisThing obj2(1, 2);   //uses Ctor #2
static ThisThing obj3 = {1,2}; //creates a default implementation CCtor using Ctor #2
```

as daniel atlass said since you implemented a CTor implantation the compiler did not generate a default implantation.

Default implementation are best be declared explicitly using `= default;` if that's the intention and there is no other Ctor implantation, same goes for CCtors.